# iOS: Draggable UIView (vertically only)

Tags: ios, uiview, drag

In my app I have a small subview that I'd like to tether in the bottom right corner and allow to be moved only vertically for a fixed distance.

I have some code to allow it to be dragged, but no further constraints:

```
- (void)viewDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:keyView];

    // move view
    keyView.center = CGPointMake(keyView.center.x + translation.x,
                           keyView.center.y + translation.y);
// reset translation
[gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:keyView];
}
```

I've looked around on StackOverflow and tried a couple of ways, but the only one that worked didn't take into account diagonal movement, and I couldn't find anything in regards to tethering it to one spot.

So does anyone know how this can be done? Many thanks

EDIT: Also, does anyone know of a good, informative reference doc (other than the Apple one) for topics of this nature?

Answer (score 1):

can you just add in a line to the view dragged code that says if keyview.centre.y is less than some threshold (where you want it to stop), then don't change it below that. eg.

```
keyView.centre = CGPointMake(keyView.center.x,
                       keyView.center.y - translation.y < threshold ? threshold : keyView.center.y);
```

also remove the change to the x parameter to stop it moving diagonally.